Does the syndrome extraction circuit determine the threshold for the surface code?
The examples of the surface code threshold in Stim all use an optimal syndrome extraction circuit. These measure the CNOT gates in an N or Z pattern and this is known to be fault tolerant.
Suppose I build a syndrome extraction circuit in a non-optimal way by measuring each stabilizer sequentially instead. After d rounds, I record the results and use PyMatching to decode - all in the usual way. The only difference is that I did not interleave and parallelize the CNOT gates of the stabilizers.
Since I am still using Stim, there's no idling error - the only errors inserted are before measurements/resets or after Clifford gates.
Should I still see a threshold? I currently do not and in fact, I see a higher logical error rate for higher distance codes. The best performing code is d=3. Is this expected to see for suboptimal syndrome extraction circuits or have I made a mistake with my Stim code?

You might want to include your code/stim circuit in your question. While your question has its own theoretical merit, it is plausible that your problem comes from a mistake in your circuits. A common mistake that can lead to the behaviour you describe is forgetting some detectors for the first round of stabilizer measurements for example.

You can use stim.Circuit.shortest_graphlike_error to check that the code distance is indeed growing in your higher distance codes.


The only difference is that I did not interleave and parallelize the CNOT gates of the stabilizers. [...] the only errors inserted are before measurements/resets or after Clifford gates.

Simulate it and check, but I expect that circuit to be fault tolerant. It's a weird noise model to not insert any idle error on the other qubits, but if you had actual qubits like that then you could measure the stabilizers sequentially. If your simulations disagree I recommend checking for mistakes in the circuit, e.g. check if circuit.count_determined_measurements() == circuit.num_stabilizers + circuit.num_observables.
In fact, I think ion traps do this. Because ion traps have low idling error, at small sizes they implement codes by sequential stabilizer measurement. It lets you use fewer measurement ancilla qubits. At some big enough size scale this would break down, since their idling error is not zero, but that's a problem for later. Honestly the more serious practical problem is probably how slow it is to do logical operation, as they typically require remeasuring all stabilizers and doing so sequentially takes a lot longer than doing it in parallel.

doesn't fault tolerance for the surface code require the X stabilizers and Z stabilizers to be measured in a specific order to avoid hook errors? Wouldn't not doing that be a potentially bad syndrome extraction circuit, whether or not the stabilizers are measured sequentially?

@user1936752 hook errors don't determine fault tolerance, they only affect the distance scaling vs patch size of your fault tolerance. Fixing a bad ordering is an easy way to get more performance out of the same number of qubits, but it's not strictly speaking required. In fact it's often beneficial to sacrifice fault distance to get some other gain that more than makes up the cost, like a shorter circuit cycle.
